# Ordering a varchar column in MySQL in an Excel-like manner

Tags: sql, mysql, natural-sort

I have a varchar column with mixed data- strings, integers, decimals, blank strings, and null values.  I'd like to sort the column the same way that Excel would, first sorting numbers and then sorting the strings.  For example:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 3.5
- 10
- 11
- 12
- alan
- bob
- carl
- (blank/null)
- (blank/null)

I've tried doing something like 'ORDER BY my_column+0' which sorts the numbers correctly but not the strings.  I was hoping someone might know of an efficient way to accomplish this.

MartinofD's suggestion works for the most part and if I expand on it a little bit I can get exactly what I want:

SELECT a FROM test 
ORDER BY 
a IS NULL OR a='',
a<>'0' AND a=0,
a+0,
a;

Pretty ugly though and I'm not sure if there are any better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT a FROM test ORDER BY a IS NULL OR a='', a<>'0' AND a=0, a+0, a;
```

Any more efficient/elegant solution would be welcome however.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `my_column+0` is equal for all strings (0).

Just use `ORDER BY my_column+0, my_column`

```
mysql> SELECT a FROM test ORDER BY a+0, a;
+-------+
| a     |
+-------+
| NULL  |
| alan  |
| bob   |
| carl  |
| david |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 3.5   |
| 10    |
| 11    |
| 12    |
+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you strictly need the numbers to be above the strings, here's a solution *(though I'm not sure how quick this will be on big tables)*:

```
mysql> SELECT a FROM test ORDER BY (a = CONCAT('', 0+a)) DESC, a+0, a;
+-------+
| a     |
+-------+
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 3     |
| 3.5   |
| 10    |
| 11    |
| 12    |
| alan  |
| bob   |
| carl  |
| david |
| NULL  |
+-------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: That doesn't accomplish the order I'm looking for.  I would like the numeric values to come first.

Comment: Much uglier, but if you really need to I added the second option above.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer.  Yours puts blanks (strings equal to '') in between the numbers and strings.  I know, I'm picky :)